# Image.OpacityMask on WinRT XAML

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-runtime

Regarding this .net XAML UIElement property, Image.OpacityMask: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743320.aspx

I am having difficulty getting OpacityMask to work in my C# / XAML project for WinRT.

Sample XAML like this:

```
<Image ...
    <Image.OpacityMask>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/alpha.png"/>
    </Image.OpacityMask>
/>
```

Doesn't seem to work, "The attachable property OpacityMask property was not found in type Image"

How does one use an alpha mask .png to mask a Image UIElement in WinRT XAML?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `OpacityMask` property on [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx) (or [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) fo that matter) in XAML for Windows Store apps. You only have [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.opacity.aspx) property available.

Comment: Thanks - any pointers for WinRT on how to use Opacity property to mask a UIElement with a bitmap?

Comment: @MJR There is no simple replacement for `OpacityMask` functionality available. You definitely can't use `Opacity` instead. For fixed image content you could include the opacity information as alpha channel of the image itself. The only way to achieve this effect would be using [Direct2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx). Such effects can be quite resource intensive though so they might not perform best on all hardware. Which could be the reason the functionality is not available in first place.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do, there are alternatives to OpactiyMask that you should check out. check out [these alternatives here.](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/07/07/Alternatives-to-OpacityMask.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that, really usefull stuff.  I end up myself using BitmapIcon, and then controlling the "mask" using the Foreground color.